# Javascript Multiplication issue with specific numbers

Tags: javascript

In javascript console type in 79.99 * 100
instead of 7999 we get 7998.999999999999
This occurs only with specific digits(80.99,80.01) etc.
Does not occur with 89.99,99.99 etc.

Is this a bug with Javascript?

Abhi.

Comment: No it's not a bug, it's been asked a million times and a quick search will reveal the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Javascript handles numbers differently and there's a problem with javascript number handler in some cases. This can be achieved by:

```
function strip(number) {
return (parseFloat(number.toPrecision(12)));
}

strip(79.99*100);
```

Comment: *Differently?* From what?

Comment: I read a javascript book in which it was written that the javascript engine handles floating numbers mechanism different as it looks.  For example, 0.1+0.2 will give 0.30000000000004 but ((0.1*10)+(0.2*10))/10 will return 0.3

Comment: I see. Well, that's not specific to Javascript at all. It's actually more tied to the IEEE754 representation than to the language.

Comment: Yep. The same is with ActionScript.

Comment: And why is this specific to certain numbers?
79.99*100 has the issue where as 89.99 does not.
Where do i find a list of such Magical numbers?

Abhi.